# Vue.js Application sometimes only responds when holding buttons for a little while on mobile

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So this is a rather strange behaviour I noticed with VueJS. On mobile browsers (Safari for example), clicking on areas with @click actions sometimes does not respond unless you hold your finger down for a few ms. Sometimes it even registers the click as a hover event, but doesn’t run the @click action.

My website I’m talking about: https://www.votify.net

Did you ever experience similiar behaviour? How could I possibly go about debugging this?

Comment: could you be more specific please

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away or here: https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-remove-the-300ms-tap-delay-in-html5-mobile-apps/